# Angular NgRx state update synchronously

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have `NgRx-Effects` in place and related action to fetch data from the service and that updates my initial `state` let's say '`schoolData`'is the state property name, which works very well.

Now, I have some event on the form from which I want to update the same state as aforesaid where in I will transform the data and will update the state.

I am aware of the `asynchronous` way of managing state, but In my case can the effect be used for updating state `synchronously`?

snippet from [NgRx.io](https://v10.ngrx.io/guide/effects): says it can have that as well.

```
Effects perform tasks, which are synchronous or asynchronous and return a new action.
```

Can anyone has a working example of this or can lead me into the right direction?

Comment: I think you should read about optimistic vs pessimistic updates https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-change-tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect logic itself is called synchronously.
When you trigger an async call inside of it, like fetching data, it "becomes" async.

But: Effects are made for isolating "side effects" like async calls.
When you don't have to do any impure side effects that you want to isolate, I would rather place this state update logic inside a reducer.

Comment: I called reducers action from component and updated the state, thanks !